# HOW to ignore the size of the browser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want objects on the site not to move out when the browser size changes.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is the code of one object that is moving out

```
div[class=ygol4] {
    border-radius: 200px;
    border: 3px solid #ffffff;

    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: #151515;
    position: fixed;
    top: 86.3%;
    left: 36%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 3;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using `display:flex;`? Where's your code?

Comment: I use `position: fixed;`

Comment: I edited the description, take a look

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#container{
  width:960px;
   margin:0px auto;
 }  
#container img{
 width:960px;
 }
 #left-column{
   width:700px;
    float:left;
      background:lightblue;
     }
     #right-column{
      width:260px;
       float:left;
       background:gold;
        }
      @media screen and (max-width:959px){
      #container{
        width:100%;
          }
   #container img{
    width:100%;
     }
     #left-column{
       width:70%;
    }
     #right-column{
       width:30%;
        }
       }
      @media screen and (max-width:640px){
      #left-column{
       width:100%;
        } 
         #right-column{
          width:100%;
          }
        @media screen and (max-width:320px){
            #container{
             width:320px;
                }
              }

           <div id="container">
           <img 
       src="https://unsplash.com/photos/osPrIcTwJy4"/>
                     <section id="left-column">
                   this is the left column 
                    </section>
                    <aside id="right-column">
                        this is the right column
                         </aside>
                           </div>
```

This is one of the most annoying searches I went through but try following this format it helped me and saved me alot of time. To understand the concept of the method check out this YouTube video https://youtu.be/fA1NW-T1QXc

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, by using "%" as a unit of measurement, you're telling the object to position itself relative to the element it's in. If that element is the `<body>` then your element will position relative to the body's size, which causes it to change with the size of the screen. You could probably fix this by surrounding your elements in a `<div>` with a pre-set `width` and `height` in pixels. Let me know if that fixes the issue!